# how to active show more button and show 3 item per page in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-views, django-templates

i'm trying to show 3 items per page and if user press on `show more` button it will load more 3 items

views.py :

```
def home_page(request):
pcgamesforhome = PCgames.objects.all()
context = {'pcgamesforhome' : pcgamesforhome}
return render(request,'html_file/enterface.html',context=context)
```

html page :

```
<div class="container">
<div class='row'>


{% for home_page in pcgamesforhome %}

     <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 website-thumb'>
                
     <a href="{{ home_page.page_url }}">
              
     <img src="{{ home_page.get_image }}" class='image_control_for_home_page_pc_games'     alt=''> </a>
                
     <h3 class="font_control_for_home_page_pc_games_name"><a href="{{ home_page.page_url }}" style="color:black">{{ home_page.name }}</a></h3> </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="text-center mt-4">                
   <a role="presentation" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg loadMore" style="width:40%">Show More</a>
</div>


<script>
$(".row").slice(0, 3).show(); //showing 3 div

$(".loadMore").on("click",function(){
    $(".row:hidden").slice(0, 3).show(); //showing 3 hidden div on click

    if($(".row:hidden").length ==0)
    {
        $(".loadMore").fadeOut(); //this will hide
        //button when length is 0
    }
})
</script>
```

so what is the wrong in my code , ( my html page now show all items in model not 3 in once )

Comment: How do you hide your items in the first place? They don't seem hidden by default. Also, `:hidden` isn't a proper selector.

Comment: Well what should I do

Comment: may be you can give them a `hidden` class by default, with a css style like `.hidden { display: none;}` and then simply remove the class for the three elements you want to show, that should be a rough sketch start.

Comment: thanks , can you explain more , maybe if you write code i will understand better

Comment: Have a look here: https://jsbin.com/rodeciyuju/edit?html,console,output

Comment: @ArnaudV it's work very good , thanks bro 
just other question , i can add collapse all when user show all items ?

Comment: Yeah, you should add the button with a `display: none;` style, and change its style at the same moment you remove the 'show more' button. For the logic of what happens when you click the 'collapse all', I guess you would just have to loop over all of the thumbnails and remove their `visible` class.

Comment: Oh my god , thanks really , you are smart

Comment: @ArnaudV hello bro i tried to add show less button when user show all data like this but it not work can you help me with this look at this code please ,, https://jseditor.io/?key=javascript-app-ver-108  ( may you need to click on JavaScript then back to html to show code )